# install4j individualization of the progressbar

Tags: progress-bar, install4j

I am new with install4j. When working with it I wondered about progress diplay.

with the install files the bar runs. After that it arrived at 100%. But in project come a series of actions after this point. These need a few seconds. During this time, the bar is at 100%. This looks like the installation is frozen. how can I adjust the progress bar more individually or what other solution is there for this problem?

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two actions before the action sequence that takes a lot of time:

- "Set messages" action with "Use status" select and "Status message" set to "Completing installation..."
- "Set the progress bar" action with "Type of change" property set to "Set indeterminate status"

Alternatively, you can also implement more fine grained reporting.